# Changing the root folder of the ssh server

Tags: ssh

There are some similar questions but not same. I don't want to change the default folder. so i want to set the ROOT FOLDER for ssh connection. I mean the only folder that the client has access to , is what i set. I want to set a path that my client only have access to it and can not use the `cd ..`.

They can't go upper folders because they don't have access and permission.

Edit: the most important thing i want to do is to have a local server with some other devices to write on it but not all files access. If there is a way better than ssh sorry for my bad question.

Thanks

Comment: You can't, really. All the commands present in e.g. `/bin/` and `/usr/bin` needs to be accessible for the system to make sense. You *could* chroot/jail the environment, but that will severely limit what they can do. *Why* do you need this? Normally Unix permissions won't really let users write to files outside their home directory and a few temp directories, and not read any sensitive files.

Comment: Sorry i have edited my question. Because i wanted to create a local network but not all of them have access to write or even read some of my data. Thank you

Comment: Why won't traditional unix permissions cover that?

Comment: You need to set `ChrootDirectory` for the said user in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (or for all users, but that's gross). There's even a ready-made commented-out example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Nikita Kipriyanov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `ChrootDirectory` in the sshd configuration for the said user, or for some group, or for all users, but that's gross.

You create a new file, say, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/chroot_some_users.conf` and put the following:

```
Match User myuser
     ChrootDirectory %h
```

If you want to have this for several users, use `Match Group groupname` and add all needed users into that group.

In modern Linux distros there is `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. In older distributions you may need to add this line there yourself; just append it at the end. When you did everything, check with `sshd -t`, and if it doesn't report any errors, it's safe to reload the configuration with `systemctl reload sshd.service`.

The user `myuser` will end up seeing their home directory as the filesystem root via SSH. Notice that they won't be able to log in via SSH, because this chroot will prevent them from seeing the shell binary and required libraries, unless you made them available in their home directory. But they still will be able to use SFTP to transfer files and forward TCP ports.

Read `man sshd_config` (completely!) and `man sshd` for many important and useful details.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is very complicated. But it's still great thank you. I should take more time to do them all later. Thanks.

Comment: Ok i was now trying to do this but I don't know where should i set the custom folder.

Comment: **Did you you read the manual page as I suggested?** It's explained. Do it. I am not joking. In the answer I set it to user's home directory, with substitution `%h`.

Comment: Sorry. Now I'm going to read it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. I think that was absolutely what i wanted. Thank you so much.